# Is tableau able to access data dynamically?

Tags: api, tableau-api, dashboard

Usually a Tableau dashboard operates on "static" data that are "attached" to the published dashboard. I wonder if it is possible to make Tableau able to read data on-the-fly (when a user interacts with it). By that I mean that the data, that should be visualized, are taken from a data base that can by "dynamic". It means, for example, that the data shown by Tableau today and yesterday should not be the same because content of the database might change. Alternatively, we might try to retrieve data from an API. For example Tableau sends a request to a HTTP server and gets a data table in form of JSON and than visualizes it. Is Tableau able to do that?

Comment: When Tableau is connected directly to a datasource it **is** as dynamic as the datasource (unless you use extracts). Any action triggering a refresh (like viewing a dashboard) will usually result in getting the latest data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Tableau can connect to live data sources such as any number of database technologies. No, it cannot send HTTP requests for JSON directly. It does a have web data connection feature if you or someone has built that web service. Here are some tips on when to use Live connections versus taking an Extract. http://mindmajix.com/use-direct-connection-data-extract-tableau/

Comment: Your second statement is not correct. Tableau can retrieve data from an HTTP/HTTPS server via the web data connector: https://community.tableau.com/community/developers/web-data-connectors?build=9300.16.0726.1843&edition=pro&lang=en-us&platform=windows&version=9.3

Comment: That is not "out of the box" though. Someone needs to build a web data connector first, which is basically a web service. I've edited my answer.

Comment: OP mentions "we might try to retrieve data from an API". Besides, the client piece is 'out of the box'. What you're saying about building a web service is analogous to having to build a database before you can connect to it in Tableau.

Comment: Can i send the tableau userid and password internally to Web Data Connector?